# If conditional for multiple raster in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, python-script-tool

I have a list of four rasters and I want to apply a lot of if then statements using Python in ArcMap 10.6. I was able get the result using raster calculator with Con statements and I tried to use the same con statements in ArcPy but I got the error message 999998 : Unexpected Error.

What could be the reason for this error?

Is it possible to do the same using If then statements instead of Con in ArcPy and, if so, how?

I am completely new to coding.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "C:\Test"
Raster1= Raster("Raster1")
outcon = Con("Raster4 " =1,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what you are trying to accomplish makes it difficult to provide a definitive answer. I suspect that the error is caused by the quotation marks in the statement. That causes it to interpret `"Raster1"` as a string instead of referencing the variable `Raster1`. Try:

```
outcon = Con(Raster4 == 1,Con(Raster2 == 1,Con(Raster3 == 1,Con(Raster1 == 1,3,Con(Raster1 == 2,4,Con(Raster1 == 3,4,Con(Raster1 == 4,3,Con(Raster1 == 5,3,Con(Raster1 == 6,5)))))),Con(Raster3 == 2,Con(Raster1 == 1,3,Con(Raster1 == 2,5,Con(Raster1 == 3,5,Con(Raster1 == 4,3,Con(Raster1 == 5,3,Con(Raster1 == 6,5)))))),Con(Raster3 == 3,Con(Raster1 == 1,4,Con(Raster1 == 2,5,Con(Raster1 == 3,5,Con(Raster1 == 4,4,Con(Raster1 == 5,3,Con(Raster1 == 6,5)))))))))))
```